# Find alternating series that converges to $ \int_0^{1/2}x\log(1+x^3)dx $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to find the alternating series that converges to $ \int_0^{1/2}x\log(1+x^3)\,dx $

Here's what I did:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[\log(1+x^3)]=\frac{1}{1+x^3}=\frac{1}{1-(-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-x^3)^{n-1}=1-x^3+x^6-x^9+-...
$$
$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=x\log(1+x^3)=x\int(1-x^3+x^6-x^9+-...)\\\\
&=x\left[x-\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^7}{7}-\frac{x^{10}}{10}+-...+ C\right]
\end{align}$$
$$
f(0)=0; C=0
$$
$$
f(x)=x^2-\frac{x^5}{4}+\frac{x^8}{7}-\frac{x^{11}}{10}+-...
$$
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/2}x\log(1+x^3)dx&=\int_0^{1/2}(x^2-\frac{x^5}{4}+\frac{x^8}{7}-\frac{x^{11}}{10}+-...)\,dx\\\\
&=\left.\left[\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^6}{6*4}+\frac{x^9}{7*9}-\frac{x^{12}}{10*12}+-...\right]\right|_0^{1/2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2^3(3)}-\frac{1}{2^6(6)(4)}+\frac{1}{2^9(7)(9)}-\frac{1}{2^{12}(10)(12)}+-...
\end{align}$$
Is my method correct?

Comment: Apart from the exponent $11$ needing to be $12$ right at the very end ... haven't you achieved your aim ?

Comment: Your mistake is at the very first step, note that $$
\frac{d}{dx}[\log(1+x^3)]=\frac{3x^2}{1+x^3}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an efficient way forward.  We write $\log(1+x^3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}x^{3n}}{n}$, which is valid for $|x|<1$.

The series converges uniformly on $[0,1/2]$ and we may exchange the series and integration to obtain

> $$\begin{align}
> \int_0^{1/2}x\log(1+x^3)\,dx&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\int_0^{1/2}x^{3n+1}\,dx\\\\
> &=\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n(3n+2)2^{3n}}
> \end{align}$$

---

It might be of interest to note that the integrand has an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions, which can be obtained by integration by parts and partial fraction expansion ([SEE HERE](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+log(1%2Bx%5E3)+x+dx)).  Hence the integral can be evaluated over any interval in closed form.  Here, we find that

$$\int_0^{1/2}x\log(1+x^3)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt 3 \pi}{12}-\frac{3\log(4e)}{16}$$

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left( -1\right)^{k-1}}{k}x^{3k}$. Making sure to multiply by $x$ *before* we integrate, the final result is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\left( -1\right)^{k-1}}{2^{3k+2}k\left( 3k+2\right)}$.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

Using
$\ln(1+z)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}x^k}{k}
$,
which converges for your range,

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{1/2}x\ln(1+x^3)dx
&=\int_0^{1/2}x\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{x^{3k}}{k}\right)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int_0^{1/2}x^{3k+1}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\dfrac{x^{3k+2}}{3k+2}\big|_0^{1/2}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k(3k+2)2^{3k+2}}\\
&=\dfrac1{5\cdot 2^5}-\dfrac1{2\cdot8\cdot 2^8}+...\\
\end{array}
$

More generally,

$\begin{array}\\
\int x^a\ln(1+x^b)dx
&=\int x^a\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{x^{bk}}{k}\right)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\int x^{a+bk}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{-1)^{k-1}x^{a+1+bk}}{k(a+1+bk)}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: The OP's question is: "Is my method correct?"

Comment: The answer is NO.

Comment: This comment is correct, but where do you explain it in your answer?